# WSO2 - Publisher API - Error when publishing API

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, publisher, wso2-governance-registry

i have one problem when i try to publish an API on the wso's store. I have this message when i try to change the state of the API and publish it.

## Products concerned

- WSO2 Governance Registry
- WSO2 Publisher
- WSO2 Store

### Error WSO 2 - API Publishing

> Failed to invoke aspect: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. APIManager endpoint URL or credentials are not definedAPI Publish might fail

The lifecycle of the API is > Development > Testing > Production but i can't publish it on the store.

I'm using the version 5.0.1 of Governance Registry and i don't use the API Manager.

Anyone has had this error? Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: Which version of API Manager you are using?

Comment: I'm using the version 5.0.1 of WSO2

Comment: We don't have 5.0.1 in [API Manager](http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/). Which product you are using?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, mistake about the version of the product. I'm using Governance Registry in the version 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using WSO2 Greg 5.0.1 and its inbuilt publisher and store components. 
When you want to publish an API, you  can not use Greg Store for that purpose since it is not an API store. 
By default, WSO2 Greg has the capability to publish to WSO2 APIManager by using following inbuilt  executors described in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Integrating+with+an+External+WSO2+API+Manager):

For Soap Services:

```
execution forEvent="Publish" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.ServiceToAPIExecutor"
```

For Rest Services:

```
execution forEvent="Publish" class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor"
```

If you have some external API Store, you have to write a custom executor for that and then you will be able to publish an API. 
Refer below links for further information on custom executors:

- [[Article] WSO2 Governance Registry: Governance Framework Extension
  Points](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/07/wso2-governance-registry-governance-framework-extension-points/)
- [Lifecycle extentions in WSO2 G-Reg - Part 1](http://janakaranabahu.blogspot.com/2012/05/lifecycle-extentions-in-wso2-g-reg-part.html)
- [How to Write a Simple G-Reg Lifecycle Executor to send mails when
  triggered using WSO2 G-Reg 5 Series.](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-write-simple-g-reg-lifecycle.html)